# Django: 'module' object has no attribute 'ChoiceField', 'MultipleChoiceField'

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I'm trying to create radio buttons and checkboxes into my forms, and am trying to use the model fields `ChoiceField` and `MultipleChoiceField` respectively for the same.

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from rango.models import Evangelized

class EvangelizedForm(forms.ModelForm):
    gender = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect(
                 choices=Evangelized.GENDER_CHOICES), help_text="Gender")
    area_of_interest = forms.MultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(
                                                    choices=Evangelized.AREA_CHOICES), help_text="Areas of interest(Upto 3)")
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Evangelized(models.Model):
    GENDER_CHOICES = (('M', 'Male'), ('F', 'Female'), ('U', 'Unisex/Parody'))
    gender = models.ChoiceField(choices=GENDER_CHOICES)
    AREA_CHOICES = (('Govt', 'Govt'), ('Entertainment', 'Entertainment'), ('Automobile', 'Automobile'),
                        ('Careers', 'Careers'), ('Books', 'Books'), ('Family', 'Family'), ('Food', 'Food'),
                            ('Gaming', 'Gaming'), ('Beauty', 'Beauty'), ('Sports', 'Sports'), ('Events', 'Events'),
                                ('Business', 'Business'), ('Travel', 'Travel'), ('Health', 'Health'), ('Technology','Technology'))
    area_of_interest = models.MultipleChoiceField(choices=AREA_CHOICES)
```

However, I'm getting the following errors while working with each type of model field respectively:

```
 'module' object has no attribute 'ChoiceField'



'module' object has no attribute 'MultipleChoiceField'
```

What seems to be wrong with my code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The models define database level types.

You must specify the data type of the model and you can specify the choices with the "choices" kwarg.

So, your models should look like this:

```
from django.db import models

class Evangelized(models.Model):
    GENDER_CHOICES = (('M', 'Male'), ('F', 'Female'), ('U', 'Unisex/Parody'))
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GENDER_CHOICES)
```

For the case of the multiple choice field you can use a [CommaSeparatedIntegerField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#commaseparatedintegerfield).

I suggest you take a look at the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.choices) for models with choices

Comment: When are ChoiceField and MultipleChoiceField model fields useful then, if not when several choices are to be considered?

Comment: @ManasChaturvedi Form fields and model fields are two entirely different things. There are no `ChoiceField` or `MultipleChoiceField` model fields, only form fields.

Comment: And when are those form fields applicable? Basically, I want to know why those form fields weren't applicable in my case where multiple choices were supposed to be given to users in the form.

Comment: @ManasChaturvedi But they are applicable, in your form. Not in your model. A form field represent a visual (well, html) representation of how that data is presented to the user. A model field represent how data is saved in the database. A `ChoiceField` doesn't  make any sense in a model, as a `Choice` is not something your database can save.

Answer (score 3):

You should use **models.CharField** instead :-) [see documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#choices)

```
gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GENDER_CHOICES)
```